# Wrong Calculation of Interest,Principal & Balance in C#

Tags: c#

I'm creating an amortization process using C#. But I'm having a problem why I get a wrong answer in the interest, principal & balance.

Here's my C# Amortization Screenshot.

[image]

Its should be like this anyway.

[image]

Here's my C# code.

```
double PV = Convert.ToDouble(txt_principal.Text);
double NPER = Convert.ToDouble(txt_nop.Text);
double RATE = Convert.ToDouble(txt_irpp.Text);
double PMT = Convert.ToDouble(txt_payment.Text);

String PMT_string = PMT.ToString("#,###.##");
String RATE_string = RATE.ToString("#,###.##");
String NPER_string = NPER.ToString("#,###.##");
String PV_string = PV.ToString("#,###.##");

int count = 0;
for (count = 0; count < NPER; count++) 
{
    dgv_table.Rows.Add(1);
    int numrows = count + 1;
    dgv_table.Rows[count].Cells[0].Value = numrows;
    dgv_table.Rows[count].Cells[1].Value = PMT_string;
    double interest = PV * RATE / 100;
    double principal = PMT - RATE;
    if (PV < PMT) 
    {
        principal = PV;
        PMT = RATE + principal;
    }
    PV = PV - principal;
    if (PV < 0) 
    {   
        principal = principal + PV;
        RATE = RATE - PV;
        PV = 0;
    }
    dgv_table.Rows[count].Cells[2].Value = interest.ToString("#,###.##");
    dgv_table.Rows[count].Cells[3].Value = principal.ToString("#,###.##");
    dgv_table.Rows[count].Cells[4].Value = PV.ToString("#,###.##");
```

Any help sir. Why the value of my interest, principal & balance are wrong?

Comment: Whats NPER, PV. where are coding standards ? for money use decimal not double.

Comment: Number of Payments and Principal Value sir.

Comment: You need to describe more clearly what your expected behaviour is (it's not clear from the screenshot how you expect the numbers to be calculated; though one could make an educated guess, such assumptions may not be correct). If you renamed your variables to have meaningful names instead of abbreviations, it would help readers understand the intent of the code. If you read through your code in relation to your description of the desired behaviour, you'd probably spot the issue. Your result is too far out from the target to be caused by just `decimal` vs `double`

Answer (score 1):

The first problem I can see is in this line:

```
double principal = PMT - RATE;
```

This is taking your interest rate away from the payment to derive the principle. That's why in the first line, you have `14,544.16` instead of `11,047.66` as the principle. Switch it to this instead:

```
double principal = PMT - interest;
```

**EDIT**: fixing the above does fix all of your results. (Whilst I hope this has helped, I've still voted to close the question: it's not really a good fit for StackOverflow's format as it's unlikely to be of use to anyone else.)